# Filtering a list based on another list using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 lists. I need to use the sort order of `item.name` in the second list to sort the first list. I need to fetch the highest value in case if there is more than 1 item with same name in the first list.

Is there a way to convert the below to use java 8 streams?

```
package com.dangdoogle.filterme;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class FunnyLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Item> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Item> secondList = new ArrayList<>();

        firstList.add(new Item("apple",20));
        firstList.add(new Item("onion",80));
        firstList.add(new Item("tomato",30));
        firstList.add(new Item("apple",90));
        firstList.add(new Item("onion",10));

        secondList.add(new Item("onion"));
        secondList.add(new Item("tomato"));
        secondList.add(new Item("apple"));


        secondList.forEach(item->{
            firstList.forEach(key->{
                if(item.getName().equals(key.getName()) && item.getValue() < key.getValue()) {
                    item.setValue(key.getValue());
                }
            });
        });

        secondList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}

class Item{

    Item(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    Item(String name,int value){
        this.name=name;
        this.value=value;
    }

    private String name;
    private int value;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of sorting `firstList`?

Comment: @AdamSiemion sorry , it shouldn't have been there. I was trying few approaches to see if I can convert to streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, Optional<Item>> maxValueMap = firstList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Item::getValue))));

    List<Optional<Item>> secondListContainsItems = secondList
            .stream()
            .map(item -> maxValueMap.get(item.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    secondListContainsItems.forEach(System.out::println);
```

this is functional way first step find max value on names and convert to map and second get by name if it exist

Comment: Thanks @kakashi hatake

Comment: for the absence of the name in the `secondList`, its worth appending `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before you collect it. On the other hand, it's better to [reduce to `Map<String, Item>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58479163/1746118) since there is a certainty of the presence of element while grouping them by an attribute.